# How to remove all rows with NA from a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

***I have***: A matrix *y* and it has two columns (the number of rows is different and depends on the input parameters). All the elements in the first columns are integers.

***I need***: for each row if the element of the second column is NA, I need to remove this row.

How can I do it? My only idea is to create another matrix and if a row from my first matrix doesn't have NA, add it to the second matrix. But I bet there's a more elegant way of doing so in R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An example with some made up data:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:3,c(1,NA,4)),ncol=2)
m[!is.na(m[,2]),]
```